# How to download Multiple Adwords account at the same time in Google Adwords Editor?

Tags: google-ads-api

Whenver I work on editor, I cannot download multiple account together.
Only when download of one account is finished , then only i can download the next account. It wastes a lot of my time. Is there any way to resolve such situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can only download a maximum of 5 at a time and unfortunately, they're downloaded sequentially. On the account selection window, hold the CTRL key and select a max if 5 accounts, then select download.